# Cannot show JSON Response, when I first navigate to a page in Android application

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, android-lifecycle

I am building a chat app currently. The problem that I faced is that when I first enter the chat activity/page, I would not be able to see the response of my JSON request call (in the form of Recycler View). The result would only show if I press the "Back" button and then re-open the same chat activity. This means that my response is late my 1 lifecycle (or similar).

In my mind, I was expecting the chat log would show up on the first attempt when I open the chat.

I have tried to look up for similar questions ins Stack Overflow, and none of them is related or solved my issues. I also have tried to move my code to execute on a different Android lifecycle (like making a request onCreate and showing the result onResume or on post resume), and the bug still unsolved.

EDIT: I requested my user's messages upon clicking the contact, and store it in an Intent object via putExtra(). So, if there are messages from previous chat, it should be stored on the Intent and passed when I navigate to the MessageActivity.java. Also, I have added my contactRecylerViewAdapter.java code

Here's the picture of how the problem looks like :
**First attempt**

[image: first attempt]

**After refresh**

[image]

Here is the code for my activity :

**MessageActivity.java**

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar chatToolBar;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    TextView nickname;

    ImageView profileImage;

    EditText edit_message;

    ImageButton sendButton;


    private MessageAdapter messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter();

    Intent intent;

    int CURRENT_USER_ID = LoginActivity.USER_ID;

    int CONTACT_ID;
    String CONTACT_NICKNAME;
    int CONTACT_IMG;
    int ROOM_ID;


    ArrayList<Message> msg;

    String BASE_URL = URL.BASE_URL;
    RequestQueue queue;


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        messageAdapter.setMessage(MessageActivity.this,msg);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        initialize();

//        System.out.println(getLifecycle().getCurrentState() + " It is here");



        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateBackend();
                msg.add(new Message(CURRENT_USER_ID,ROOM_ID,edit_message.getText().toString()));
                edit_message.setText("");
                messageAdapter.setMessage(MessageActivity.this,msg);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateBackend() {
        String url = BASE_URL +"add-message/";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
               showMessages();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Failed to send message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("room",Integer.toString(ROOM_ID));
                params.put("sender_user",Integer.toString(CURRENT_USER_ID));
                params.put("receiver_user",Integer.toString(CONTACT_ID));
                params.put("message",edit_message.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showMessages() {
        String url = BASE_URL + "get-message/" + ROOM_ID +"/";
        StringRequest stringRequest =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                msg.clear();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray =  new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        msg.add(new Message(jsonObject.getInt("sender_user"),ROOM_ID,jsonObject.getString("message")));
                    }
                    messageAdapter.setMessage(MessageActivity.this,msg);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Failed to show messages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    private void initialize() {

        chatToolBar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(chatToolBar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        chatToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });


//        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//        actionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

//        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//        View actionBarView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar,null);
//        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.message_rec_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        nickname = findViewById(R.id.username);
        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.custom_profile_image);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        edit_message = findViewById(R.id.text_send);


        intent = getIntent();
        CONTACT_ID = intent.getIntExtra("contactId", -1);
        CONTACT_NICKNAME = intent.getStringExtra("contactNickname");
        CONTACT_IMG = intent.getIntExtra("contactImage", R.drawable.defaultpic);
        ROOM_ID = intent.getIntExtra("roomID", -1);
        msg = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("messages");

        nickname.setText(CONTACT_NICKNAME);
        profileImage.setImageResource(CONTACT_IMG);



    }
}
```

**MessageAdapter.java**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

    final static int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 1;
    final static int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 2;
    ArrayList<Message> messageList;

    private Context mContext;

    public MessageAdapter(){
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.outgoing_chat,parent,false);
            return new MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.incoming_chat,parent,false);
            return new MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Message message = messageList.get(position);
        holder.show_message.setText(message.getMessage());

        //Remember to set up for profile pic
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(messageList.get(position).getSenderID() == LoginActivity.USER_ID) {
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        } else {
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }
    }

    public void setMessage(Context mContext, ArrayList<Message> messageList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.messageList =messageList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView show_message;
        public CircleImageView profile_image;

        MessageViewHolder(View itemview){
            super(itemview);
            profile_image = itemview.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            show_message = itemview.findViewById(R.id.show_message_current_user);
        }
    }
}
```

**contactRecViewAdapter.java**

```
public class contactRecViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<contactRecViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<ContactModel> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Message> msg = new ArrayList<>();

    Context mContext;

    String BASE_URL = URL.BASE_URL;
    int CURRENT_USER_ID = LoginActivity.USER_ID;
    int PRIVATE_CHAT = 1;

    int ROOM_ID;

    RequestQueue queue;
    public contactRecViewAdapter() {}


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contacts_list,parent,false);
       return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

        holder.contact_name.setText(contacts.get(position).getContact_name());
        holder.contact_profile_image.setImageResource(contacts.get(position).getImage());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkRoomCreated(position);


                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MessageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("contactId",contacts.get(position).getContact_id());
                intent.putExtra("contactNickname",contacts.get(position).getContact_name());
                intent.putExtra("contactImage",contacts.get(position).getImage());
                intent.putExtra("roomID",ROOM_ID);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("messages",msg);

                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    private void checkRoomCreated(final int position) {
        String url = BASE_URL +"find-room/" + CURRENT_USER_ID + "/"  +contacts.get(position).getContact_id()+ "/";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    if(jsonArray.isNull(0)) {
                        createRoom(position);
                    } else {
                        JSONObject jsonObject =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        ROOM_ID = jsonObject.getInt("room");
                        getMessage();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Request to find room failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void getMessage() {
        String url = BASE_URL + "get-message/" + ROOM_ID +"/";
        StringRequest stringRequest =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                msg.clear();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray =  new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        msg.add(new Message(jsonObject.getInt("sender_user"),ROOM_ID,jsonObject.getString("message")));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to show messages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void createParticipants(int position) {
        String url = BASE_URL +"participants/";
        ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<>();
        idList.add(CURRENT_USER_ID);
        idList.add(contacts.get(position).getContact_id());
        for(final int id :idList) {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("User " +id  + " added to participants");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Try to create new participants but failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("room", Integer.toString(ROOM_ID));
                    params.put("user", Integer.toString(id));
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    }

    private void createRoom(final int position) {
        String url = BASE_URL +"room/";
        StringRequest stringRequest =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    ROOM_ID = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                    createParticipants(position);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Try to create room but error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params =  new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name",CURRENT_USER_ID + " and " + contacts.get(position).getContact_id());
                params.put("type",Integer.toString(PRIVATE_CHAT));
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.contacts.size();
    }

    public void setContacts(ArrayList<ContactModel> contacts, Context mContext) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView contact_name;
        private ImageView contact_profile_image;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            contact_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            contact_profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_profile_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should call `showMessages();` when the activity is created(onCreate) not in the button listener.

Comment: @MaiconHellmann Oh..sorry I miss a detail here.. I have call the request for getting messages from my database, when I click on the contact...so the data should  be "transfer" on the Intent object